# Surface of Cone

Tags: 3d, solid-geometry

[image]

A cone is cut by a plane ($z=d$). ($0<d<c$)
The top point of the cone is $A(a,b,c)$

Button of the Cone is a circle on $z=0$ plane and center of it is $O(0,0,0)$.

If $a=b=0$ then

$$\frac{c-d}{c}=\frac{r_1}{r}$$

$$r_1=r\frac{(c-d)}{c}$$

$$S=\pi r_1(\sqrt{r^2_1+(c-d)^2}+r_1) $$

What is the formula for surface of the cut cone If $a^2+b^2\neq 0$  ?

Thanks a lot for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, cutting by the plane $z=d$ does not change things much. The resulting cone is similar to the bigger cone with the base in $z=0$. The similarity factor is $(c-d)/c$, so the area is $(c-d)^2/c^2$ times the area of the bigger cone.

So I'm going to consider the cone with the base the circle of radius $r$ centered at O, and the vertex at $(a,b,c)$. The base has area $\pi r^2$, of course. The question is what to do with the lateral surface. Here is the calculus approach (I can't think of another one, actually):

The base circle is parametrized by $(r\cos t, r\sin t,0)$. Using the equation of the line segment from this point to $(a,b,c)$, we arrive at the parametrization of the entire surface: 
$$
\vec r(t,s)=\langle sa+(1-s)r\cos t, sb+(1-s)r\sin t, sc \rangle,\qquad 0\le s\le 1, \quad  0\le t\le 2\pi
$$
The area is the integral of $|\vec r_t\times \vec r_s|$. Let's do this: 
$$\vec r_t=  (1-s) \langle -r\sin t, r\cos t, 0 \rangle$$
$$\vec r_s=\langle a-r\cos t, b-r\sin t, c \rangle$$
and the cross product simplifies to 
$$\vec r_t\times \vec r_s = r(1-s)\langle c\cos t, c\sin t, r-a\cos t-b\sin t \rangle$$
Integration with respect to $s$ yields a factor of $1/2$, hence the lateral area is 
$$A=\frac{r}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{c^2+(r-a\cos t-b\sin t)^2}\,dt$$
When $a=b=0$, the answer is $A=\pi r\sqrt{c^2+r^2}$. But when either of them is nonzero, we get a complete [elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Finally,  some informal reasoning to show that this outcome is not surprising. You can think of the skewed circular cone as a right cone with elliptical base. Recall that the perimeter of the base enters the computation of lateral area of a right circular cone. But the length of an ellipse is expressible only in terms of elliptic integrals -- which is why they are called elliptic integrals.

Comment: According to symmetry, I think $A(a,b)=S(\sqrt {a^2+b^2})$ can be. Can we simplify more the elliptic integral that you gave ? thanks a lot for answer

Comment: $$A=\frac{r}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{c^2+(r-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin (t+t_0))^2}\,dt$$ $$A=\frac{r}{2}\int_{t_0}^{2\pi+t_0}\sqrt{c^2+(r-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin (u))^2}\,du$$  If the integral periodic So result must be $$A=\frac{r}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{c^2+(r-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin (u))^2}\,du$$ Could you please check my idea? Thanks

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, the area depends only on $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. This can be also inferred from the integral using the identity $a\cos t+b\sin t = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos (t-t_0)$ and the change of variable $\tau=t-t_0$. Or better yet, orient the axes so that the vertex is $(a,0,c)$ to begin with. Either way, this does not change anything essential. Here's a concrete example "simplified" with Maple: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29863189/elliptic.png) .

Comment: I see what you mean. I will search more about elliptic integrals. It generates nice results but I really expected to see a simple elementary result of the area expression.